# Asynctask get percentage of the progress in java

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, percentage

I have a `AsyncTask` that is unzipping files. Is it possible to get the percentage of the progress of the `AsyncTask` to show it in a horizontal `ProgressBar`?

Comment: Is your question more about calculating the progress or displaying the progress?

Comment: Displaying the progress

Comment: Nice tutorial here http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-asynctask-example-with-progress-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onProgressUpdate` in your `AsyncTask`.  Then call `publishProgress` from within the background thread.  `onProgressUpdate` will be invoked on the UI thread with the parameter from `publishProgress`.

You determine the type of the progress parameter with the second type argument in `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask has method onProgressUpdate(Integer...) that you can call each iteration for example or each time a progress is done during doInBackground() by calling publishProgress().

Refer to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more details